# How to hide Elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hide, show

I want that the text ist hidden in the beginning and after clicking the button it is displayed. I would be really greatfull if someone would find the mistake in my code.

```js
function F1()
{
  var x = document.getElementById("step1DIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <button onclick="F1()"> <b>Step 1</b> </button>
  <div id="step1DIV">
    <p> text </p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `style.display` is not available until it's set. I recommend having `.hide{ display:none; }` in CSS then have `Element.classList.add('hide')` and `Element.classList.remove('hide')` or `Element.classList.toggle('hide')`. Unless you want to do a lot of typing, I generally recommend using CSS classes to style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give it an initial style that hides it in the HTML.

```js
function F1()
{
  var x = document.getElementById("step1DIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
  <button onclick="F1()"> <b>Step 1</b> </button>
  <div id="step1DIV" style="display: none;">
    <p> text </p>
  </div>
```

But inline styles are poor design, it's better to use a class with CSS.

```js
function F1()
{
  var x = document.getElementById("step1DIV");
  x.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="F1()"> <b>Step 1</b> </button>
  <div id="step1DIV" class="hidden">
    <p> text </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: even better to utilize the HTML standard attribute `hidden`

Comment: @RonnieRoyston Classes and CSS are generally preferable because you can easily change the presentation in one place.

Comment: Specifically speaking to hiding elements though: [The hidden attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/interaction.html#the-hidden-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Try to initially set the `display` of your step1 DIV to `none`. Either using inline styling or CSS.

You can also try to run your function on page load.

Answer (score 0):

I just defined it as 'none' to begin with as such:

```
<div id="step1DIV" style="display: none">
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to toggle the `hidden` attribute [defined in the HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/interaction.html#the-hidden-attribute).

```js
function F1 () {
  document.getElementById("a").toggleAttribute("hidden");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <button onclick="F1()"> <b>Step 1</b> </button>
  <div id=a>
    <p> text </p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```